# How to invoke context menu through content js of chrome extension for an webelement?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

**Requirement:** To invoke contextmenu on a webelement which is highlighted through a chrome extension.

**Usecase:**

1. I have written a chrome extension which highlights webelement on a webpage.
   for example: textarea.
2. Logic of highlighting webelement is written in content.js of extension.
3. Now I want to invoke right click on the textarea(webelement) to display context menu with some options.

**Actual Result:** Context menu is getting invoked but its replacing page content.

**Expected result:** I want to invoke context menu with clickable mouse options and dont want page content to be replaced.

**Question:**

1. So how do we invoke context menu on textarea or any webelements?
2. Any alternative for innerHtml which will help to display context
   menu?

Below is the sample of invoking context menu:

```
webElement[i].addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
    console.log('context menu')
    e.preventDefault();
    webElement[i].style.display = "block"
    webElement[i].innerHTML = '<h2>Contextmenu items</h2><ul> <li>Option1</li> <li>Option2</li> <li>Option3</li></ul> '
});
```

Note: There are many examples where customized context menu can be displayed but in all those cases there is a html available separately with css and js whereas here it has to be handled through content.js itself as its being called in chrome extension.

Comment: Note that you're not invoking the context menu of the browser, but only showing your own menu. In this case all you need is to create a new element with `position: absolute`, add it to `body`, and position per getBoundingClientRect of the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `appendChild`:

```js
webElement[i].addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
    console.log('context menu')
    e.preventDefault();
    //webElement[i].style.display = "block"
    const child = document.createElement('div');
    // set css here
    // child.style = "color: red"
    child.innerHTML = '<h2>Contextmenu items</h2><ul> <li>Option1</li> <li>Option2</li> <li>Option3</li></ul>';
    webElement[i].appendChild(child);
});
```

Comment: Hi @init-gy, thank you. Above solution is working when document.body.appendChild() but not for webElement[i].appendChild() though function call is happening. It will help if context menu for webelement[i] is displayed.